# How can I Enable/disable data or WiFi in android programmatically in ruby (DEVICE)?

Tags: ruby, automation, wifi, calabash

Hello I need turn off the wifi/network of a device programatically in ruby.

I just found to do this in Java ! I am automating tests with calabash and we will need test on the devices, not on the simulators. I tried ifconfig already, but just worked on the simulators.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer in the calabash android google group. I think you might be able to use the adb approach to enter Settings and change it there.

Link to thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/zdFJpgxnflU

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lasse !
I found this explanation, but it is in Java...
I know that iOS don't have a solution, only if I connect in some wifi that I can manipulate with adb commands.

I found this solution to run in android devices: Only command that works

(For selecting Next element on the screen) 
(%adb shell input keyevent 20)

(For selecting previous element on the screen) 
(%adb shell input keyevent 23)

(For clicking on the selected element) 
(%adb shell input keyevent 19)

These commands only works on simulators:

adb shell svc wifi enable 
adb shell svc wifi disable (its not working on all devices, but might work for you).

## #